How can I install old version of Mosquitto on my old Mac?
I should install mosquitto 1.5.11 on my macbook running macOS Catalina (10.15.7).
The recommended approach with brew doesn't work - brew doesn't support old versions.
I tried to download old .rb file of 1.5.8 version and run it with brew, but the installation fails:
Error: Parameter 'value': Expected type Symbol, got type NilClass

I tried to install Fink, but it fails to compile.
I wanted to compile the source of the mosquitto myself, but it returns the following error:
/Users/me/mosquitto-1.5.11/lib/mosquitto.c:57:10: error: implicit declaration of function 'mach_absolute_time' is invalid in C99
      [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        ticks = mach_absolute_time();
                ^
1 error generated.

What else should I try?

Install Windows or Linux on your old Mac.
